# How can I configure 2 step filter chain for webflux security

Tags: spring-security, spring-webflux

I need to support 2 types of auth:

1. trust system where the tokens are injected by an autoconfigured filter.
2. postman like usecases where we get tokens from an inner app and test what our services return. This only works in our corp network (if that details is important).

My task is to validate the tokens on the server side in a way that if either of the methods is valid, I should allow the access.

My code for the initial (naive) implementation demonstrating the functionality is:

```java
RemoteAddressSource remoteAddressSource = new WebFluxRemoteAddressSource(exchange);
        return validateNotBlank(token)
                .switchIfEmpty(Mono.defer(() -> iafTokenValidator.validateToken(remoteAddressSource)
                        .onErrorResume(AuthenticationFailedException.class, e -> tfTokenValidator.validateToken(remoteAddressSource))))
                .onErrorResume(AuthenticationFailedException.class, e -> sendErrorResponse(e, exchange))
                .switchIfEmpty(chain);
```

While working and denies and allows as expected, there are several problems with this approach:

1. This couples both forms of authentication instead of having 2 classes for them.
2. In case of not valid, the end user always "sees" the latter error message while it could stem from the first method.
3. I'm sure there is a proper way to do that with a properly configured filter-chain, though I haven't found any to this point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have come up with something that works, though I'm not fully happy about it.

I wanted a solution where the token runs through both options, and if either validates, the request is allowed, but I wanted them to be totally separated and oblivious to each other, which I have partially achieved through TokenAuthManager.

Still, when the none trust form is deprecated, we'll need to change the AuthManager, rather than just deleting this code.

Also, I don't like if statements and try/catch blocks for exception handling with reactive operators, so still not ideal.

As least it's in 1 class, so we're not looking at a lot of work:

```java
 @Override
    public Mono<Authentication> authenticate(Authentication authentication) {
        ServiceAuthentication serviceAuthentication = (ServiceAuthentication) authentication;
        String stripped = serviceAuthentication.getCredentials().toString().replaceAll("Bearer ", "").trim();
        try {
            ServicePrincipal principal = stv.validate(stripped, (String) serviceAuthentication.getDetails());
            log.debug("client {} from ip {} allowed", principal.getName(), authentication.getDetails());
            //if this is valid, return
            authentication.setAuthenticated(true);
            return Mono.just(authentication);
        } catch (TokenException e) {
            log.debug("token {} invalid for TF", authentication.getCredentials());
            if (serviceAuthentication.isPureTf()) {
                return Mono.error(new BadCredentialsException("The provided TF token is invalid", e));
            }
            return iafTokenValidator.authenticate(serviceAuthentication);
        }
    }
```